# Ruby BCrypt hash comparison not working

Tags: ruby, hash, bcrypt

I am a new comer to Ruby, so apologies if this question has already been answered. I have read the other questions and still cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

I am creating hashed passwords for storing in a db like this:

```
new_user.password = BCrypt::Password.create(unhashed_password)
# Write the user to database
new_user.store_user
```

I then retrieve the user from the db by checking against the inputed user name, and then check the password like this:

```
# Get user from the database
def self.get_user(check_user_name)
db = User.open_db
user = User.new
user_arr = db.execute("SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE user_name = ?", check_user_name).first
db.close
# if the user exists check the password
if user_arr.size != 0
  print "Enter your password  : "
  # Get password from user
  user_input_password_attempt = gets.chomp
end
# Parse the db user into a user class if password guess is correct
stored_password = BCrypt::Password.new(user_arr[2])
if user_input_password_attempt == stored_password
  @@users_logged_in += 1
  user.user_id = user_arr[0]
  user.user_name = user_arr[1]
  user.password = user_arr[2]
  return user
end
:no_user
```

end

My problem is that the var stored_password is returning a hash and != user_input_password_attempt
I have read the Ruby-Doc and googled this extensively

Comment: Based on [documentation](http://bcrypt-ruby.rubyforge.org/classes/BCrypt/Password.html), `==` is one of the custom methods for `Password`. So, think it should be `if stored_password == user_input_password_attempt`, not the other way around.

Comment: It works like this: if BCrypt::Password.new(user_arr[2]) == user_input_password_attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `==` you are actually calling the `==` method defined on the object on the left hand side, passing the right hand side as argument:

```
a == b
```

is equivalent to

```
a.==(b)
```

Depending on the object you call the `==` method you might receive a different result. In other words:

```
a == b
```

might or might not return a different result than

```
b == a
```

While personally I think this is nonsense and equality operators should be `transitive`, `symetric` and `reflexive` the BCrypt people have decided to implement it in another way:

```
def ==(secret)
  super(BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(secret, @salt))
end
```

(taken from http://bcrypt-ruby.rubyforge.org/classes/BCrypt/Password.html#M000009)

This means that you have to write:

```
stored_password = BCrypt::Password.new(user_arr[2])
if stored_password == user_input_password_attempt
  ...
end
```

in order to call the `==` method on the `Password` instance.